# ACL on root owned folder on CentOS7 not giving access

Tags: centos, bash, access-control-list

Using an ACL to give a non-root user access to a root-owned directory-

As root-

```
mkdir /testdir
chmod 0400 /testdir
setfacl -dm u:mike:rwx /testdir
getfacl /testdir
 # file: testdir
 # owner: root
 # group: root
 user::r--
 group::---
 other::---
 default:user::r--
 default:user:mike:rwx
 default:group::---
 default:mask::rwx
 default:other::---
```

As mike-

```
ls -la /testdir
ls: cannot open directory '/testdir': Permission denied
```

selinux is enabled. I looked for denials in the audit log but didn't find any, although I can't imagine selinux is not the cause of the denial. I simply want to keep this folder locked away from everyone except the one user mike, so how can I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed the default ACL mode for this user. You need to change the ACL mode without default option `-d` like the following:

```
setfacl -m u:mike:rwx /testdir
```

Default ACL will work for newly created files/folders under this folder.

Comment: Thank you. I incorrectly used the 'd' flag as it is used in NFSv4 ACLs, thinking it meant dir inheritance, which I now see it does not. Would you mind explaining what a default ACL in this case (i.e. as I was incorrectly using it above) would actually do, and why it doesn't provide access?

Comment: @hotkarl: As I said in the answer, default ACL is used to determine ACL of newly created objects under your dir `man acl`.